# Массив из php в js

Tags: php, javascript, массивы

### нужно передать двумерный массив из php в js

формирование массива

```
while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   $count++;
   $arr[] = $res2;
}
```

---

Функция JS

```
function ShowTable(ind)
{
    //$("[name = "+ind+"]").css('display', 'block');
    alert(ind['index']);
    $("tr[name = "+ind['index']+"]").after(
    '<tr name="$tId" onclick="ShowTable($tId)">'+
        '<td><input type = "checkbox" name = "$tId"></input>'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td><?=$arr[$i]['index']?></td>'+
        '<td>$tSource</td>'+
        '<td>$tMessage</td>'+
        '<td>$tDate</td>'+
        '<td>s</td>'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs active">Stop</button></td>'+
    '</tr>');
}
```

---

Пытаюсь передать

```
<?
   for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
   {
       for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
       { 
            if($arr[$j]['index'] == $index1) $indexCount++;
            else $index1 = $arr[$j]['index'];
       }
       if($arr[$i]['index'] != $index)
       {
    ?>
    <tr name="<?=$arr[$i]['index']?>" onclick="ShowTable(<?=$arr[$i]?>)">
        <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "<?=$arr[$i]['index']?>"></input>
        <td><?=$arr[$i]['index']?></td>
        <td><?=$arr[$i]['source']?></td>
        <td><?=$arr[$i]['message']?></td>
        <td><?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $arr[$i]['timeToSend'])?></td>
        <td><?=$indexCount?></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs active" onclick="StopSend(<?=$arr[$i]['index']?>)">Stop</button></td>
    </tr>
   <?
       }
        $index = $arr[$i]['index'];         
   } 
   ?>
```

---

на выходе получаю значение `ind['index']` undefined, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вместо `<?=$arr[$i]['index']?>` передавайте `<?=$arr[$i]?>`. Вы обращаетесь в JS к несуществующему индексу. А еще у вас в строке `'<td><?=$arr[$i]['index']?></td>'` ошибка. С кавычками беда. На всякий случай напоминаю, что в JS php-код не выполняется.

Comment: В том то и дело, что передаю я `onclick="ShowTable(<?=$arr[$i]?>)"` но ничего с этого не выходит... а с ковычками потом разберусь, сначала нужно чтобы алерт вывел что-нибудь толковое

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Никогда не пишите так, передавайте данные через ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте данные так (с PHP 5.3):

```
onclick="StopSend(this.getAttribute('data-source'))" data-source='<?= json_encode($arr[$i], JSON_HEX_QUOT); ?>'
```

А считывайте так:

```
function ShowTable(ind)
{
    var data = JSON.parse(ind);
    alert(data['index']);
    // Ваш действия
}
```

Comment: я уже представил то, что будет в html`ке)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, лучше не стоит. Поберегите нервы. :) Человек учится, весь код далек от идеального

Comment: я пробовал ранее так делать...

Comment: попробовал сейчас, при нажатии на таблицу ничего не происходит...

Comment: @АнтонБурак, в консоль посмотрите, какие там ошибки?

Comment: @VenZell, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: ошибка появляется после нажатия на таблицу. если отправлять
`onclick="ShowTable(<?=$arr[$i]['index']?>)"` то все ок

Comment: @АнтонБурак, кажется, я кавычки пропустил в ответе. Попробуйте обновленный код из первой строчки.

Comment: @VenZell, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @АнтонБурак, покажите часть кода внутри `onclick="StopSend`, во что преобразуется вывод.

Comment: @VenZell, мне не StopSend нужен... я отправляю ShowTable

Comment: @АнтонБурак какая разница. И там, и там `json_encode` должен быть. Мне нужен кусок преобразованного кода

Comment: @VenZell, я только начинаю разбираться с JS, php и т.д., где этот кусок найти можно?

Comment: @VenZell, `<tr name="1" onclick="ShowTable('{"0":"11797","id":"11797","1":"1","index":"1","2":"eqw","source":"eqw","3":"444","destination":"444","4":"444","message":"444","5":"1466633100","timeToSend":"1466633100","6":"1","status":"1"}')">` оно?

Comment: @АнтонБурак, обновил ответ. Посмотрите первую строку кода.

Comment: @VenZell, `<tr name="<?=$arr[$i]['index']?>" onclick="ShowTable('<?= json_encode($arr[$i], JSON_HEX_QUOT); ?>')">`
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
`<tr name="1" onclick="ShowTable('{" 0":"11797","id":"11797","1":"1","index":"1","2":"eqw","source":"eqw","3":"444","destination":"444","4":"444","message":"444","5":"1466633100","timetosend":"1466633100","6":"1","status":"1"}')"="" role="row">`

Comment: @АнтонБурак, попробуйте новый вариант

Comment: @VenZell, отлично, все работает, огромное спасибо