# Как перекинуть массив из PHP в JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Имеется 2 одномерных PHP массива и 1 двумерный массив JS

Массивы PHP:

```
$GA_lat[] = [-35.165034,35.696121,-36.113032,-36.852924,-36.868273]
$GA_lng[] = [174.162854,174.300132,174.559536,174.750234,174.711450]
```

Нужно переместить данные из масивов PHP в двухмерный массив JS.
(Данные из ячейки 0 в 0 ячейку двумерного массива и т.д.)

Что бы получилось:

```
var locations = [
  ['1', -35.165034, 174.162854, 5],
  ['2', -35.696121, 174.300132, 4],
  ['3', -36.113032, 174.559536, 3],
  ['4', -36.852924, 174.750234, 2],
  ['5', -36.868273, 174.711450, 1]
];
```

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530201/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-php-%d0%b2-js?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

На сервере, преобразуем данные в `json`

```
    $GA_lat = [-35.165034,35.696121,-36.113032,-36.852924,-36.868273];
    $GA_lng = [174.162854,174.300132,174.559536,174.750234,174.711450];

    $transformData = [];
    $coumtGA =  count($GA_lat);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $coumtGA; $i++) {
        $transformData[] = [strval($i+1), $GA_lat[$i], $GA_lng[$i], $coumtGA-$i];
    }

    echo json_encode($transformData);
```

На клиенте, получаем json(например через ajax или записываем его куда нибудь в field) и преобразуем его в объект:

```
var dataFromServer = JSON.parse(answerFromServer);
```